# How to export all products(simple.configurable,etc) with all variant and image from Magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, export

all I want to export all products from Magento 1.9.4.1.
So, Is there any script available?
We have 15000 total products.
Please if you have please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: am not sure about the images but you can easily exports products from backend and if you are in hurry you can use standalone script to get the job done quickly just let me know your requirement script is recomended when you have more than enough products

Comment: @Pramod thanks for reply. In short I want to all product list with all attributes. any how. so please give me solution.